# Hints to solve this integration

Tags: definite-integrals

I stumbled upon this integration $$\int_0^{\pi/4}(1+\cos2\theta)^2\,d\theta.$$ And I have no idea on how to proceed with it. It would be very helpful if someone would provide me with some hints. Thank you.

Comment: Expanding $(1+\cos(2\theta))^2$ gives $1+2\cos(2\theta) + \cos^2(2\theta)$. The first two terms are straightforward to integrate, for the term $\cos^2(2\theta)$, use the double angle formula!

Answer (score 3):

Using the identity, $\cos^2(2\theta)=\dfrac{1+\cos(4\theta)}{2}$,we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/4}(1+\cos(2\theta))^2\,d\theta&=\int_0^{\pi/4}(1 + 2 cos(2\theta) + \cos^2(2\theta)) \, d\theta\\[10pt]
&=\int_0^{\pi/4} \left(1+2\cos(2\theta)+\frac{1+\cos(4\theta)}{2}\right)\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Got it!! thanks

Comment: Pleased to hear.  You're welcome.  -Mark